# How is a verilog function translated to hardware

Tags: verilog, hardware, hdl

I know that that when you make multiple instances of a module, separate hardware is created for each instance. But what about functions. What exactly happens when I call the same function from different parts of a code?

Answer (score 2):

Synthesizable verilog functions will be inferred to a combinational circuit usually as a series of multiplexers.

Comment: Each time a function is invoked, its like instantiating that combinational block. So, am I correct?

Comment: That's not correct. A synthesizable verilog function is an electronic circuit. In verilog, you are doing hardware not software. You should know the difference.

Comment: I mean, lets say I call a function 10 times from different places in same module, will it synthesize same set of hardware 10 times or a single hardware will be inferred 10 times? I think the latter option might be correct.

Comment: Probably yes but that will depend on your synthesis toolbecause there will be some optimizations to the gate size. You'll have to look for the documentation or reference manual. Once you've understood the translation, you'll be able to estimate the gate size.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I understood it as tool specific behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the function will be 'inlined' each time it is called.  What happens afterwards is up to the synthesis software.  It is possible that some of these instances will be redundant and will be removed.  It is possible that some that are not entirely redundant can be combined by inserting multiplexers.  Logic path length, complexity, timing requirements, etc. will all affect the result.

This sort of optimization can take place across modules.  Synthesizers can be very good about removing or even duplicating logic as necessary to reduce the overall size and to meet timing constraints.